# Make sessions work in Yii

Tags: php, session, yii

Sad Yii is poorly documented.

I have built an application with two modules (user and admin modules) each with its login function.

Each user is users are referred to using `Yii::app()->getModule('module_name')->user`

**Problems**

1. Either sessions not enabled or sessions never expire. Point is users are always logged in.
2. When both users are logged in within the same browser, one logging out logs out the other even with using `getModule('module_name')` for reference. Problem is users are always logged in.

**What I have tried**

I have

```
if($identity->authenticate()){
  Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user->login($identity,5); 
  //hoped the user will be logged out after 5 seconds but didn't work
}
```

also included the following in config/main.php

```
'session'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            // 'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'timeout'=>10,
        ),
```

Any help with solving the above will be appreciated. Need these users' sessions to start expiring

Comment: Have you read up on the CWebUser class?  There is a logout() method that you could use to logout the current user. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#logout-detail

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.larryullman.com/2011/05/03/using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had to pass `false` to the `logout` function. The `false` is for the $destroySession argument indicating that only that session of information should be cleared. Passing `true` or leaving blank will clear all session information.
[CWebUser::login()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail).

To solve the session never expires issue, I had to use 'CDbHttpSession' as the session class.

```
"class" => "CDbHttpSession"
```